# Android list item

Tags: android

Can any one tell me What this line of code do? i learnt it in an android tutorial but could not understand it, could any one tell me the specifics of it?.

```
Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.prem.firsttry.STARTINGPOINT");
```

Comment: see [Class.forName(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) java doc : *Returns the Class object associated with the class or interface with the given string name*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) loads and links a Java class. Constructs a `Class` object and gives it to you. You can go ahead and make an Object out of it by [`newInstance()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29).

Most popular use of such method is to check if a particular class exists and can be loaded (such as some JDBC driver). If not, this method throws exceptions. This also causes static initialization on the said class.

Answer (score 1):

A call to Class.forName("X") causes the class named X to be dynamically loaded (at runtime). A call to forName("X") causes the class named X to be initialized (i.e., JVM executes all its static block after class loading). Class.forName("X") returns the Class object associated with the "X" class. The returned Class object is not an instance of the "x" class itself.

Class.forName("X") loads the class if it not already loaded. The JVM keeps track of all the classes that have been previously loaded. This method uses the classloader of the class that invokes it. The "X" is the fully qualified name of the desired class.